# Why won't my string won't return to the assertion?

Tags: c, string, return

I am making a code that zippers two strings together.

Ex:
s1= "1 3 5 7"
s2= "2 4 6"
returns: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"

```
char* merge2(char* s1, int wwa1, char*s2, int wwa2, char*ans){
    //printf("commence next recursion\n");
    char currentWord1[45]; char currentWord2[45];//longest word in english has 45 letters
    currentWord1[0]='\0'; currentWord2[0]='\0'; 
    //printf("after current word\n");

    for(int n=wwa1; s1[n]!=' ' && n<strlen(s1); n++){
        char addition[] = {s1[n],'\0'};
        strcat(currentWord1,addition);
        wwa1=n;
    }
    //printf("%s\n",currentWord1);
    wwa1+=1;
    for(int w=wwa2; s2[w]!=' ' && w<strlen(s2); w++){
        char add[] = {s2[w],'\0'};
        strcat(currentWord2,add);
        wwa2=w;
    }
    //printf("%s\n",currentWord2);
    wwa2+=1;

    if(strlen(currentWord1)>0 && strlen(currentWord1)>0){
        wwa1+=1;
        wwa2+=1;
        strcat(currentWord1," ");
        strcat(currentWord2," ");
    }
    else if(strlen(currentWord1)>0 && strlen(currentWord1)==0 && wwa1<strlen(s1)){
        wwa1+=1;
        strcat(currentWord1," ");
    }
    else if(strlen(currentWord1)==0 && strlen(currentWord1)>0 && wwa2<strlen(s2)){
        wwa2+=1;
        strcat(currentWord2," ");
    }

    strcat(ans,strcat(currentWord1,currentWord2));

    int anslen = strlen(ans);
    int straddlen = strlen(s1)+strlen(s2);
    /*
    printf("len ans: %d\n", anslen);
    printf("tot len: %d\n", straddlen);
    printf("ans: %s\n", ans);
    printf("%s, %d, %s, %d, %s\n",s1,wwa1,s2,wwa2,ans);*/

    if(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)==anslen-3){
        if(anslen>=2)
            ans[anslen-2]='\0';
        //printf("\nYOU ARE RETURNING: %s.\n",ans);
        return ans;
    }
    return merge2(s1,wwa1,s2,wwa2,ans);
}
```

The answer simply won't return to where it is asserted to see if it is correct.
Not even a failed assertion, just won't get there.

I have tried everything I can think of, which may not be much because this is only my 3rd month of C.

It should return the proper string from what I can tell.

Please help.

Comment: What does "The answer simply won't return to where it is asserted" mean?  I don't see any assert() statements in the code, so the obvious meaning can't be it.

Comment: "longest word in english has 45 letters" That means, your arrays must be 46 characters to hold it. What is this function supposed to do? What are the parameters? How do you call it? BTW: You even add multiple words and spaced into these arrays. You never check how much you added to these `currentWord` arrays

Comment: You should drop a ton of comments to explain what that code is doing. Where do you get that condition `(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)==anslen-3)`? Lots of magic numbers...

Comment: `if(strlen(currentWord1)>0 && strlen(currentWord1)==0 &&` One of them should be Word2 I guess...

Comment: The code in this question is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74497261/how-do-i-get-my-function-to-recur-and-merge-the-strings-together-instead-of-cras?noredirect=1#comment131507157_74497261 posted by a different user earlier today - what's going on? Two kids in the same CS class with the same homework?

Comment: "longest word in english has 45 letters"  --> There are other [longer canidates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English).  Better to use a macro than code 45 in multiple  places.  IAC, For "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", you need `currentWord1[45+1];`